# Column 'task_id' in order clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT a.*, p.*, t.*, r.*, n.* 
FROM prop_assigns AS a 
LEFT JOIN properties AS p 
ON (p.property_id = a.property_id)
 LEFT JOIN tasks AS t ON (t.task_id = a.task_id)
 LEFT JOIN reminders_tasks AS r ON (a.assign_id = r.assign_id)
 LEFT JOIN notes_view AS n ON (p.property_id = n.property_id)
 WHERE a.user_id = 3 AND a.task_id <> 0 AND
 a.assign_done = 0 AND n.user_id = 3 ORDER BY task_id desc
```

MySQL a répondu: Documentation

```
#1052 - Column 'task_id' in order clause is ambiguous
```

it look long sql any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `task_id` is in more than one table.  You need to specify which you mean:

```
SELECT a.*, p.*, t.*, r.*, n.*
FROM prop_assigns AS a LEFT JOIN
     properties AS p
     ON (p.property_id = a.property_id) LEFT JOIN
     tasks AS t
     ON (t.task_id = a.task_id) LEFT JOIN
     reminders_tasks AS r
     ON (a.assign_id = r.assign_id) LEFT JOIN
     notes_view AS n
     ON (p.property_id = n.property_id)
WHERE a.user_id = 3 AND a.task_id <> 0 AND a.assign_done = 0 AND n.user_id = 3
ORDER BY t.task_id desc;
---------^
```

Comment: thank but i had other error
'#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay'

Comment: i find the solution SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=50